# Passport/axios not post username password

Tags: php, laravel, axios

I am trying to `POST` username, password of `auth` to Laravel/Passport but it always return `null`

```
axios.post('http://localhost:8000/api/login', {
    withCredentials: true,
    auth: {
      email: 'agent@test.com',
      password: 'qwerty!@#$%^'
    }
  })
  .then(res => {
    console.log(res);
  })
```

**PassportController.php**

```
public function login(){
    if(Auth::attempt(['email' => request('email'), 'password' => request('password')])){
        $user = Auth::user();
        $success['token'] =  $user->createToken('MyApp')-> accessToken;
        return response()->json(['success' => $success], $this-> successStatus);
    }
    else{
        return response()->json(['email'=>request('email')], 401);
// I return email to see value
// return response()->json(['error'=>'Unauthorised'], 401);
    }
}
```

**api.php**

```
Route::post('login', 'PassportController@login');
```

I checked everything many times, feel everything is ok, but for some reason data not send to passport.

conosle log:

> POST http://localhost:8000/api/login 401 (Unauthorized)

```
{email: null}
email: null
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved my issue, the problem is no need to send `credentials` and `auth` via `axios` because from back-end laravel accept post data not auth data, so I passed `email` and `password` via form-data not auth:

```
axios.post("http://localhost:8000/api/login", {
    email: "agent@test.com",
    password: "qwerty!@#$%^"
  })
  .then(res => {
    console.log(res);
  });
```

Now I got token in back-end.

Answer (score 2):

Laravel is probably accessing the POST data's values with `request`. The `axios.post` method's second parameter is the object sent as POST data, so you probably meant to just pass the email and password as top-level keys:

```
axios
  .post(
    "http://localhost:8000/api/login",
    {
      email: "agent@test.com",
      password: "qwerty!@#$%^"
    },
    { withCredentials: true }
  )
  .then(res => {
    console.log(res);
  });
```

I suspect that you may be mixing up authentication in general with [HTTP ("Basic") Authentication](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Authentication). The `auth` key is part of the `config` object that you can pass as a third parameter to `axios.post`, which would control just that. I do not think this is what you are after, but just adding it here for completeness. Note that basic auth accepts an *username* and a password:

```
axios
  .post("http://localhost:8000/api/login", {}, {
      withCredentials: true,
      auth: {
          username: "agent@test.com",
          password: "qwerty!@#$%^"
      }
  })
  .then(res => {
    console.log(res);
  });
```

Comment: First code is failed, return the same but for second example, it return nothing, in network tab it return `200 OK` but no data in preview, I should say it work good on `postman` I use `POST` and set email password as form-data and it return token.

Comment: Ah, and noticed I got error in console, CORS origin

Comment: Ah, classic. Good that you found it!

Comment: So, I'm little confused here, should CORS in Laravel or Axios? I already have CORS middleware in laravel, also set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in axios, still the same error.

Comment: The server should set the CORS header. As a browser client, you shouldn't need to set anything in Axios related to that. If you look at your Network tab in your browser's developer tools, do you see `Access-Control-...` headers?

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-Headers: AUTHORIZATION,CONTENT-TYPE` this is it. also I think console error contains some new words: `The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header in the response is '' which must be 'true' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.`

Comment: + I use `barryvdh cors` if need to know

Comment: Looks like there's a `'supportsCredentials' => false` in the [configuration by default](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors/tree/64111b0c74e22dd0167d65a57dfbc7db413e6723#configuration). Try changing that to `true`?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have much more experience with Laravel. I would suggest asking another question specifically about getting `withCredentials` CORS requests working with Laravel!

Comment: Thanks for your help, Sure I do that

Comment: So I figured out this problem related to cors, I added this manually to bootstrap/app.php and error solved, `header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');` and I got the same first error in my question now: `401 (Unauthorized)`